# Open street MAP doesn't show in API >23

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm very new to the osmdroid library! I'm trying to make an app (navigator) which detects and alerts the users about special events.

I followed the osmdroid wiki and I successfully added a map on low API, but in 8.0 (API 26) map doesn't show. I tried to add permissions, but map keeps not showing, although it requests the location permission.
 Can you please suggest me a solution? In lower APIs it works perfectly.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    } else {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},2);

        } else {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }

    }
}
```

According to the osmwiki, the higher APIs need to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions.

Comment: According to [How to use the osmdroid library](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) you will also need the permission `INTERNET`, at least in your AndroidManifest.xml. Also check your logs.

Comment: be sure you ask for permissions before inflating the layout